# How do I achieve non-strict ordering for two cats.effect.IO monads?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have a computation that has three steps, like so:

```
import cats.effect.IO
def step1: IO[Unit] = ???
def step2: IO[Unit] = ???
def step3: IO[Unit] = ???
```

I can combine them together sequentially using a simple for comprehension:

```
val c: IO[Unit] = for {
  _ <- step1
  _ <- step2
  _ <- step3
} yield ()
```

In our case, `step3` depends on both `step1` and `step2`, so we don't want `step3` to run until both `step1` and `step2` complete. But `step1` and `step2` are independent. The above for comprehension is a bit deficient because `step2` does not start until `step1` completes. How do I express this independence?

I've been looking around for something like `scala.concurrent.Future.sequence`, that would convert from `Seq[IO[A]]` to `IO[Seq[A]]`. Even better would be something to convert from `(IO[A], IO[B])` to `IO[(A, B)]`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it. This seems to work:

```
implicitly[cats.Cartesian[IO]].product(step1, step2)
```

(Returns an `IO[(Unit, Unit)]`.)

**EDIT**: Even more succinctly:

```
import cats.implicits._
step1.product(step2)
```

Comment: More succinctly written as `cats.Cartesian[IO].product(step1, step2)`

Comment: Similar, and also useful is `cats.Applicative[IO].sequence`. Will convert a `Seq[IO[A]]` to a `IO[Seq[A]]`.

Answer (score 0):

In the [third paragraph of the README](https://github.com/typelevel/cats-effect#cats-effect----) it explicitly states that the cats-effect library does *not* handle concurrency or parallelism.